# Using command in ssh authorized_keys breaks SFTP functionality

Tags: ssh, sftp, openssh

Scenario 1 : hostA sftp files to and from hostB as user1 using RSA authentication. This works fine.

Scenario 2 : To allow only specific commands for user1 to run on hostB from hostA, i added command="somescript" in the authorized_keys files on hostB. This works fine but now SFTP from hostA to hostB is broken.

```
hostA# sftp -v user1@hostB
....
....
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3120, received 2720 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10837.6, received 9448.1
debug1: Exit status 0
Connection closed
```

Scenario 3 : Remove command from authorized_keys from hostB. SFTP starts working fine.

Any ideas why specifying command in authorized_keys breaks sftp?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this question (it's likely that your command is being run instead of the sftp subsystem, but I can't turn than in an authoritative answer) -- but I've voted for it to be moved to superuser.stackexchage as it's not really about programming.

Comment: What is `somescript`? If it is something creating output and not starting `sftp-server` then it is obvious that you break the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for this.

First of all, it's very important that your command doesn't generate any output if it's not run in an interactive console. I do this by using the following lines at the beginning of the script run by command:

```
if [ "`tty`" != "not a tty" ]; then
   cat /etc/issue.net
fi
```

Then, at the end of your executed script you should execute the provided SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND if it exists:

```
if [ x$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND == x ]; then
    bash -li
else
    $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
fi
```

This is how I've managed to have a command compatible with ssh, scp, sftp and rsync.

Comment: I'm surprised I am the first two upvote this two years later.  It totally worked for me when I kept shaking my head trying to understand why sftp would not work.  Now I can lock down the command a bit.  Thx!